# Default value in mandatory column is not showing up

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, managed-metadata, default-value

I made a content type inside a library. Made a Template of the library since it needs to produce hundreds of other libraries. There is one field in the content type that is mandatory and library by library it will need to change its default value.

In word the properties panel on the side of the document does not show said default value, while clicking on 'file' (backstage view of the document) it does. As a matter of fact the document allows itself to be saved despite not being in the frontal properties panel.

This is bugging me for weeks now, as I have already checked the column inside the content type in the library and it shows the default value. I have checked 'column default value settings' and it is there, and I even add it again for the sake of being 200% sure.

I cannot put the default value in the original content type (site column) since it will change library by library and it will be set when the library is created.
I even checked the default Word Template.dotx inside forms and this template does carry the default value.

There is no problem with Excel and PowerPoint because those 2 do not have the property panel on the side but they lead you to the 'file' view, where the default value is there.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: When you say you "made a content type inside a library", did you just add columns to a library or did you create a real Content Type with previously defined site columns? That bit is unclear.

Comment: my experience is that MMD defaults are only applied when a file is uploaded to a library, not when it is created via the New  button.

Comment: I created a content type and later I inserted it inside the library deleting the default 'Document'. If you create a file with 'new button' in Excel and PP you can see your default. You can see it also in Word in the 'backstage' area File - properties, not in the properties panel on the side of the document.